# Highscore list comes out as undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, local-storage

I'm finished with a game for school and it's functioning well. But I need to store the score from each game in local storage. I can present the individual score but if I want to have an array with scores the values are 'undefined'. Not sure where I get it wrong because the local storage shows the data, although twice over...
Any chance i could get a hint from you?

At the start of the game I want to display the scores, if there are any. I do this with:

```
let score = document.querySelector('#score')
let scores = []
if (scores.length > 0) {
  let score = document.querySelector('#score')
  let extract = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('scores'))
  let highscore = document.createTextNode(extract.Nickname + ' - ' + 
  extract.Score)
  score.appendChild(highscore)
}
```

When the player is finished with the game and got all the correct answers I use this code to push the object:

```
window.scoreNickname = document.getElementById('name').value
window.scoreTime = seconds + 's ' + totalTimeSum % 1000 + 'ms'
let scoreData = {
    Nickname: window.scoreNickname,
    Score: window.scoreTime
}
scores.push(scoreData)
window.localStorage.setItem('scores', JSON.stringify(scores))
let extract = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('scores'))
let highscore = document.createTextNode(extract.Nickname + ' - ' + 
extract.Score)
score.appendChild(highscore)
```

But all I get us undefined. In local storage I have this information:

```
scores: [{"Nickname":"Adam","Score":"18s768ms"},
{"Nickname":"Adam","Score":"18s768ms"}
```

Comment: `let scores = []
if (scores.length > 0) {` will never execute the conditional block

Comment: `extract` would be an array, just like `scores` was. It doesn't have a `.Nickname` property

Answer (score -1):

Try with :

```
let extract = window.localStorage.getItem('scores');
```

I think you don't need to JSON.parse a JSON object

Comment: Yes you do. Localstorage stores strings (in this case a JSON string), not objects.